# trying to use PyAudio on python 3.9.6 on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyaudio, portaudio

I used brew to install PortAudio and pip3 to install PyAudio.
I have the latest versions installed.
When I tried to use speech_recognition module it says:

> Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.

Comment: Please, add full error output

Comment: Really, that's all I got.

Comment: Be sure you are on the correct copy of `python3` (if you have more than one, the one in which the module was installed) with a `PYTHONPATH=` set if not installed in the default path (prefix`/lib/python`version).

Comment: I found that PyAudio.py and PyAudio-0.2.11-py3.9.egg-info are in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages. Is this enough?